# Как написать альтернативу программы, чтобы следующие пункты использовались хоть 1 раз?

Tags: python

Три выхода: напишите альтернативную версию упражнения 7.4 или упражнения 7.5, в которой каждый пункт следующего списка встречается хотя бы один раз: • Завершение цикла по проверке условия в команде while. • Управление продолжительностью выполнения цикла в зависимости от переменной active. • Выход из цикла по команде break, если пользователь вводит значение 'quit'
Меня интересует конкретно 2 пункт (• Управление продолжительностью выполнения цикла в зависимости от переменной active.)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При вызове 'quit' выходит ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста. Сильно только не пинайте, если написал неправильно. Вторую неделю только изучаю)

Comment: Вы написали неправильно! Вопрос тут, имею в виду:-) Код надо текстом помещать. И код у вас неправильный :-) тут - надо минимально воспроизводимый код, а у вас кусок кода только.  Как его запускать, чтобы вам помогать?:-)

Comment: Функция `input()` возвращает строку. Вы сравниваете сороку, к примеру, строку `'3'` с целочисленным значением `3`. Для того чтобы исправить данную ошибку в вашем коде при сравнении используйте `int()` к примеру `int(message) < 3`. Но есть нюанс, при `message == 'quit'`, `int(message)` выдаст исключение, поэтому выход из цикла при этом значении должен происходить раньше чем Вы начнете приводить `message` к `int`

Comment: А вообще, если в дальнейшем хотите получать адекватные и подробные ответы, ознакомитесь с правилами ресурса и в частности с разделом по оформлению вопросов. Присоединяюсь к замечанию @Сергей